# Ios BLE extended Advertising example

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Does anyone know how to implement BLE extended advertising using Core Bluetooth or any other library in ios . From BLE 5.0 there should be option of sending 255 Bytes in advertising pockets as described [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/exploring-bluetooth5-whats-new-in-advertising/)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Core Bluetooth is an abstraction on top of the Bluetooth hardware.  It does not provide full access to Bluetooth capabilities.  The only advertising data you can send is via [`startAdvertising`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising)

Comment: Is there any way to send advertising package larger than 31 Bytes from iOS peripheral? According to WWDC19, ios supports extended advertising up to 120 Bytes [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901/)

Comment: They support extended scan, not extended advertising in Core Bluetooth

Comment: I am new to ios development so this may be very common for Apple but I am very surprised that they went on to stage and claimed the support for extended advertisement when they actually don't do it.